# c# Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string[]' to 'string' 40 37 emailsearch

Tags: c#

How can I show the EmailsList

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string)' has some invalid arguments  C:\Users\วิน7\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\emailsearch\emailsearch\Form1.cs    40  21  emailsearch

```
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            {
                Coderbuddy.ExtractEmails helper = new Coderbuddy.ExtractEmails(result);
                EmailsList = helper.Extract_Emails();
                MessageBox.Show(EmailsList);

            } 
        }
```

Comment: unless your question directly relates to C# 4.0 language features, it is better to just tag it C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asuming EmailsList is a list of strings and you want to put it in one messagebox, you could propobly get away with something like:

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
    {
        Coderbuddy.ExtractEmails helper = new Coderbuddy.ExtractEmails(result);
        EmailsList = helper.Extract_Emails();
string tmpEmalis;
  foreach (string email in emails)
     {
         tmpEmails = tmpEmails + email + "\r\n";
     } 
MessageBox.Show(tmpEmalis);
    }
```

If EmailsList is not a List then it's realy hard to guess what it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Your EmailsList is typed like an Array of string. However, MessageBox.Show can only display one string.
So, if you want to display every email, you need to iterate like this :

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
{
     Coderbuddy.ExtractEmails helper = new Coderbuddy.ExtractEmails(result);
     EmailsList emails = helper.Extract_Emails();
     foreach (string email in emails)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(email);
     } 
}
```

Comment: Though technically it makes sense, I would hate the UI which shows me a message box A NUMBER OF TIMES, one after another...

Comment: You can concatenate e-mails or implement the ToString() method like you said and display only one time but it's not the sense of the initial question ;-)

Comment: Well, that's not my question :-) But your comment makes more sense than your initial answer to me :-)

Comment: I didn't see it. Corrected ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`EmailsList.ToString()`?

If it's your class, implement `ToString()` method the way you need.